# Excel macro for averages

Tags: excel, vba, average

I have a problem with a VBA script. I guess the solution is simple, but I just wasnt able to figure it out....

So basically, I have a workbook that contains many worksheets. Each worksheet contains the exact same format of a table (same number of rows and columns). What I wanted to do was to create a new worksheet and in that worksheet, have averages of all those values.

So for example in cell B2 I want to have average of cells B2 from all the other worksheets. I therefore created a macro that does this, this is not a problem, the problem is however, that in that macro, all sheets are referred to by their names and since I have many of these workbooks with differently named sheets, this would not work. I therefore tried to change the name of the first sheet to actual reference of sheet - i.e. Sheet(1) and the last one as Sheet(x) - where x is the number of sheets I calculated previously. Unfortunately the code doesnt work, could anyone please suggest to me how to modify this so that it works properly? I am only copying the problematic part of the code:

```
x = Sheets.Count
Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(x)
Range("B2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGE(Sheets(1):Sheets(x)!RC)"
```

Comment: well all the other stuff I already have in VB, I guess this cannot be such a big problem and I thought it would have a very simple solution - basicaly all I need is to be able to choose all worksheets in that workbook (apart from the one created where the averages are to be displayed)

Comment: yes, but still no luck

Comment: well from what I found, the number in the brackets refers to the nth worksheet, so first one should be Sheets(1) and variable x was calculated before and is equal to the number of sheets (see above), so I assumed Sheets(x) would then lead to the last worksheet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. You are not offseting your sheet names (in fact, you're not even *using* the sheet names.  In the context of a formula, `Sheets(1)` is meaningless.  You need to use `Sheets(1).Name` and offset it appropriately:

```
"=AVERAGE('" & Sheets(1).Name & ":" & Sheets(x).Name & "'!RC)"
```